# Predator/prey-like simulations for dark tetrad traits?

Tags: evolutionary-psychology

Is there research attempting to model & simulate the spread of "negative genes" (and by this I mean just the phenotypic effect thereof) like the [dark tetrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad#Dark_Tetrad) traits in a human population? For background, [Lotka–Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations) have been widely used for predator-prey simulations and so forth. However, in a human population, you'd probably need something more sophisticated.

Off the top of my head, narcissism and psychopathy are high-risk-high-reward evolutionary strategies: maybe you end up king (getting elected president being too recent evolution-wise), or maybe you end up a serial killer (and eventually caught/killed) or just shunned/banished as a mere egotist. Risk sensitivity alone [has been studied in this respect](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep08242):

> We observe that risk aversion only evolves when the gamble is a rare event that has a large impact on the individual's fitness. As such, we suggest that rare, high-risk, high-payoff events such as mating and mate competition could have driven the evolution of risk averse behavior in humans living in small groups.

However, a pauper seldom ended up king. Also, it is known that the mostly human ability to hoard resources/prey can have a dramatic impact on predator-prey simulations, [making resource/prey extinction possible for instance](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ecolecon.2014.02.014). (I guess something might need to be said about [scatter hoarding](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2830248/) in animals; the substantial difference is that inherited socio-economics status [SES] has no known animal equivalent, methinks.)

So, if something more specific wasn't studied, did someone study risk aversion in conjunction with inheritable SES in an evolutionary game/simulation?